# Setting Gitlab-runner build path in Linux machine

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, rhel6, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a Linux(RHEL) runner and creating a CI/CD pipeline to build the project using .yml file from GitLab.

When I try to run the pipeline using .yml from GitLab, it automatically creates a folder as depicted below.

[image]

I want to change this initialized Git repository into my "**/home**" folder. Have created a Git directory under home folder "/home/new_build" using  command.

Tried setting the "**GIT_DIR**" path on the RHEL server, but no changes observed to the Git Initialization directory from .yml file.

Any other steps I could infuse to change the Git Initialization directory, which can be picked by .yml file from GitLab.

Comment: This oath is controlled by the gitlab runner and where it clones the repo to. You can configure this in the gitlab runner config https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#default-build-directory

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, the below process worked, hence posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this field in the etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml on your linux machine:

```
**builds_dir = "<target-dir>"**
```

In the linux machine:

```
-gitlab-runner uninstall
-gitlab-runner install --user=gitlab-runner --working-directory=<target-dir>
-create the <target-dir>
-chmod 777 <target-dir>
-chown gitlab-runner <target-dir>
-gitlab-runner restart
```

**target-dir  is the new repository path, where the git-clone and git-build will take place.